# Swift 5: Move cell from one section to another section in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am doing some table view practices. And I want to implement a function that moves one cell from one section to another section by using the moveRowAt method. When I move/arrange a cell within the same section, it works fine. However, when I move a cell from one section to another section, it will throw me an error like this: [image]

This is the moveRowAt function:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath)
    {
        // Move data
        let todo = todos[fromIndexPath.section][fromIndexPath.row]
        todos[fromIndexPath.section].remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
        // move from one section to another section
        if to.section != fromIndexPath.section
        {
            todos[to.section].insert(todo, at: to.row)
            //        Update View
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath, to: to)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        else
        {
            todos[fromIndexPath.section].insert(todo, at: to.row)
            //        Update View
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath, to: to)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }

    }
```

The declaration of todos is :

```
struct ToDo {
    var name = ""
    var checked = false
    var details: String = ""
}

var todos: [[ToDo]]
```

Thanks for helping and sharing your idea!

Comment: I try to use tableView.reloadData() as update view part. And it works this time. But I am confusing that what is wrong when I use tableView.moveRow?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call

```
tableView.moveRow(at: fromIndexPath, to: to)
```

yourself as this will cause a recursive loop just do the remove and insert only